Tcolorbox theorem with boxed title to the left of the body of the theorem
I would like to have an "exercise" environment, preferably as a newtcbtheorem, with the following simple layout:
+–––+
|3.2|  (opt. description) Content of the box (first line) 
+–––+  Content of the box (second line)

       Content of the box (second paragraph)

Box is over, normal text resumes...

So there is a simple boxed "title" that contains only the counter, with a dynamically adjusted width based on the counter size, and some rule and bg color, and the box's contents is to the right of this title-box, appropriately indented.
I have tried with attach boxed title to left top instead of top left, but it seems the title is meant to be either at the top or at the bottom. Here a MWE:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[skins,hooks,xparse,breakable,theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{exercise}{}
  {
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=yellow,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm},
    boxed title style={
      sharp corners
    }
  }
  {ex}


\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{exercise}{opt. description}{first-exercise}
Content of the box (first line)\\
Content of the box (second line)

Content of the box (second paragraph)
\end{exercise}

\noindent
Box is over, normal text resumes...

\end{document}

This however has the title box to the top left instead of to the "left top", and the description is also in the box.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I mean it's not a "problem" in that sense, I just want to have an environment that looks like what I have crudely shown in ASCII-"art"

The problem is that you want a certain layout, but don't have this layout yet. If you would like help in finding a solution to this problem, a test file would be helpful so we don't have to type all the boring stuff like \documentclass etc.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've added a MWE, which doesn't match my design requirements however. It would be nice if there were an easy way, but I've done a lot of googleing and I'm afraid the solution will be to instead work with tikz to place the counter appropriately, and draw a box around it, which is beyond my current TeX knowledge

You could remove the counter from the title and use an overlay to place it next to the box:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[skins,hooks,xparse,breakable,theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{exercise}{}
  {
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    overlay={%
      \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-2.5mm,draw] at (frame.north west) {\thetcbcounter};
    },
    attach title to upper={~},
    description delimiters parenthesis,
    theorem name,
    grow to left by=-1cm
  }
  {ex}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{exercise}{opt. description}{first-exercise}
Content of the box (first line)\\
Content of the box (second line)

Content of the box (second paragraph)
\end{exercise}

\makeatletter
\addtocounter{tcb@cnt@exercise}{100}
\makeatother


\begin{exercise}{opt. description}{second-exercise}
Content of the box (first line)\\
Content of the box (second line)

Content of the box (second paragraph)
\end{exercise}

\noindent
Box is over, normal text resumes...

\end{document}



Thanks a lot! The one thing that didn't look good was the spacing, there always was a small indent before the description (the space between the empty title and the description), and when there is no description, there was an indent at the beginning due to attach title to upper={~}. My fix was to replace this last line with:
detach title, before upper={\setbox0=\hbox{\tcbtitle\unskip}\ifdim\wd0=0pt\else\tcbtitle\enspace\fi}, separator sign={\negthickspace}
